# Artificial Pollination of Adenium

Tags: prior-art, china, cn104585015

The method of artificial pollination of Adenium has been popular in Taiwan for a long time, and there are other similar artificial pollination methods.

How can I bring my concerns to the attention of a Chinese patent examiner?

Comment: The method of artificial pollination of Adenium has been popular in Taiwan for a long time, are similar artificial pollination method, we are opposed to this patent application, thank you.
沙漠玫瑰的人工授粉的方法已經流行在台灣很長一段時間，類似人工授粉的方法，我們反對這個專利申請，謝謝。

Comment: This crochet pollination technique has been widely used in the Desert Rose cultivation industry and there are other similar artificial pollination methods. We have used this common technique for more than 15 years and should not be granted a patent, Thank you!

Comment: @RoseChen This is an English-language forum. Please post your comment in English. Thank you.

Comment: Tools and methods have been widely used for a long time, I think it should not be through this application, thank you.